# Replace a variable symbolic expression instead of a constant value in a symbolic matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

This code can create a matrix of symbolic variables to a given size.

```
clc
clear all
close all

% Get size input from user
M=input('input a scalar number: ');

% Create symbolic vars matrix
m=2+((2*M)+1)*2;
n=2+((2*M)+1)*2;
H=sym('a%d%d',[m,n]);
for m=1:2+((2*M)+1)*2
    for n=1:2+((2*M)+1)*2    
        if m==1 && n>2
            H(m,n)=0;
        elseif m==2 && n>((2*M)+1+2)
            H(m,n)=0;
        elseif n==1 && m>2
            H(m,n)=0;
        elseif n==2 && m>2+((2*M)+1) && m<=(2*((2*M)+1))+2
            H(m,n)=0;
        elseif m>2 && m<=2+((2*M)+1) && n>2 && n<=2+((2*M)+1)&& n~=m
            H(m,n)=0;
        elseif m>2+((2*M)+1)&& m<=(2*((2*M)+1))+2 && n>2+((2*M)+1)&& n<=(2*((2*M)+1))+2 && m~=n
            H(m,n)=0;
        end       
    end
end
```

Now, after running this code, if you enter for example `M=3`, You will have a `16-by-16` matrix.

Now, instead of each `=0` in the above for loops matrix, I want to set the matrix element equal to an expression. For instance:

```
for m=1:2+((2*M)+1)*2      
    for n=1:2+((2*M)+1)*2

        % Other conditions

        if m==2 && n<=(2*M)+1
            H(m,n)= (i*w)+(1/tqr) + (1/tqe) + (1/td0);
        end

        % Other conditions

    end
end
```

As you can see, this code defines the expressions for a `a23 ... a2(2M+1)`.
Now I want to replace all these expressions in my symbolic matrix with for loop automatically.

Know my question is: How can I do it?

Comment: A note on this: `2+((2*M)+1)*2`. You use it several times and it can be simplified greatly! `2+((2*M)+1)*2 = (2 + 2*M)*2 = 4*(1+M)`. Secondly, do the variables in your expressions have to be symbolic or can they  just be numerical functions?

Comment: Thanks to your answer. 
I wrote this term by this form for my next program. Because I need to see this term, but yes, that's true. It can be simplified.
They are numerical functions.